# Remove regex string from project using Gradle

Tags: android, regex, gradle

I would like to remove all my logs commands from my java (android) project on Release build using Gradle.

I'm using regex (which is correct):

> '/Logger.log[^,]+[^L]+Logger.DEBUG[^;];/g'

and the following gradle script:

```
task dropJavaDebugLogs << {
    FileTree javaFiles = fileTree("src/main/java") {
        include "**/*.java"
    }
    String regex = "Logger.log[^,]+[^L]+Logger.DEBUG[^;];";
    javaFiles.each { File javaFile ->
        content = content.removeAll(regex);
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what i doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `content = content.replaceAll(regex, "");`. And you do not have "g" option in your code.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks but it's not working..:/

Comment: Are you sure your regex is matching the contents? Please provide some input data.